# Install FFMPEG in Redhat Linux via rpm for a non root user

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rpm

How can i install ffmpeg rpm for a non root user on linux server. I tried installing the package using

```
rpm -ivh ffmpeg-devel-0.10.15-1.el6.i686.rpm
```

The above package shows number of dependency errors. As there are more than 50 packages to install to satisfy dependencies, is there any simpler way to install ffmpeg via rpm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just [download a binary of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

```
curl -O http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
tar xf ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
```

- Your new binary will be in the `ffmpeg-git-64bit-static` directory.
- If your kernel is older than 2.6.32+ then you won't be able to use this.
- If you're using a 32-bit system, then replace the `64bit` with `32bit`.
- You won't need to "install" it; just execute it directly or point your script to the new binary.

Comment: And, just in case anyone's worried about downloading binaries from random sites, the one in this answer is linked to from the [official download page](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html), so it _should_ be safe.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot install rpm as non-root user.

You can **extract** content of those packages:

```
rpmdev-extract ffmpeg-devel-0.10.15-1.el6.i686.rpm
```

BTW if you are root and you want to install debuginfo, you should not do that using rpm (and not even with yum), but do:

```
debuginfo-install ffmpeg
```